# Is it possible to redirect users when they click on a shared link to a page rather the page shared with facebook share?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am practicing facebook sharing with Open graph meta tags. Everything works perfectly. I do share this way.

```
function PostShare(mylink) {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'share',
                href: mylink,
                hashtag: '#Ozhay',
            }, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error_message) {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Wallpost', 'Facebook', window.fbactivity_name, window.fbactivity_id);
                } else {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Wallpost', 'No', window.fbactivity_name, window.fbactivity_id);
                }
            });
        }
```

I would like to set a different URL for the share dialogue so when ever a user publishes a link on his/her profile the other user should not get redirected the same page which was shared. He/she should be redirected to a url of my choice. Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: Just call that function with the link to be shared

Comment: @WizKid a bit more explanation

Comment: To share you call the function PostShare. You just need to pass in the URL you want to share

Comment: If I pass the URL then that URL will be shared I want a redirect URL not the URL it self

Comment: That is not possible directly; you can only redirect the users what follow the link from Facebook once they arrive at the shared URL - either via JavaScript, or server-side (in that case, you need to implement an exception for the FB scraper.)